# Symfony3 404 NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, symfony

I am developing with Symfony3, and now my problem is "404 error" when trying to access "http://localhost:8000/auth page"

**dev.log**

```
[2016-04-18 18:30:14] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "GuideBundle\Entity\MedicalStaff object not found." at D:\Elya\КПИ\6 семестр\TSPP\mg\vendor\sensio\framework-extra-bundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter.php line 66  []
```

It worked before (I don't remember what I had done to fail it).
My **routing.yml**

```
auth:
    path: /auth
    defaults: {_controller: GuideBundle:Security:login}
```

**SecurityController.php**

```
 class SecurityController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/auth", name="auth")
         */
        public function loginAction(Request $request)
        {
            //Here is the code, If I comment It nothing changes and I don't use here any MedicalStaff object
        }

    }
```

**MedicalStaff.php** is in GuideBundle\Entity folder

```
namespace GuideBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MedicalStaff
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="medical_staff")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GuideBundle\Repository\MedicalStaffRepository")
 */
class MedicalStaff
{
    //here are methods and properties
}
```

Can anyone say what can cause such type of problem?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the controller Symfony tries to access? The error message indicates that it is trying to serve a route that makes use of a param converter (which fails) instead. You can use the `debug:router` and `router:match` commands to check which route would actually being accessed with the request or take a look at your application's log.

Comment: Not a 404: "GuideBundle\Entity\MedicalStaff object not found."

Comment: @ManoDestra I get 404 error in browser

Comment: @xabbuh trying to `php bin/console router:match /auth` I'm getting "var\cache\dev/assetic/routing.yml" does not contain valide UTF-8 YML.

Comment: Check this file/line for the offending item: `D:\Elya\КПИ\6 семестр\TSPP\mg\vendor\sensio\framework-extra-bundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter.php line 66`, rather than your controller.

Comment: Sorry if I've read this wrong, but why are you using YML and @Route to generate the same route?

Answer (score 1):

This YML

```
auth:
    path: /auth
    defaults: {_controller: GuideBundle:Security:login}
```

Will conflict with your annotation

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/auth", name="auth")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        //Here is the code, If I comment It nothing changes and I don't use here any MedicalStaff object
    }

}
```

Use one and not both, check your config to see which you SHOULD be using.